# Call ms-sql stored procedure with ObjectQuery

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How to call a stored procedure with ObjectQuery?
Here is my code:

```
using (var dc = new DAL.ImpulseScreens.ImpulseScreensEntities())
{
    string query = "EXECUTE dbo.GetACLentry @AppName, @WindowsUserID, @EntryType, @PassPhrase";

    var data = new System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<System.Data.Common.DbDataRecord>(query, dc);
    data.Parameters.Add(new System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter("AppName", Settings.ParentAppName));
    data.Parameters.Add(new System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter("WindowsUserID", Settings.WindowsUserName));
    data.Parameters.Add(new System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter("EntryType", (int)type));
    data.Parameters.Add(new System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter("PassPhrase", PASS_PHRASE));

    foreach (var x in data)
    {
         var i = x.GetOrdinal("ImpulseUserID");
         var v = x.GetValue(i);
    }
}
```

But it gives an exception:

> "The query syntax is not valid. Near identifier 'dbo', line 1, column
>   9."

Comment: @Sergii: They are the same, both work in MSSQL Management Studio. But neither work in ObjectQuery.

Comment: have you tried to remove `dbo.`? Try these queries `GetACLentry @AppName, @WindowsUserID, @EntryType, @PassPhrase` and `EXEC GetACLentry @AppName, @WindowsUserID, @EntryType, @PassPhrase`

Comment: @Sergii: yeah, it still gives exception

Comment: Does it work if there is a simple select statement instead of the stored procedure?

Comment: @Sergii: Yeah, select statements work

Comment: Alas, it's not currently possible, see [Server-side execution of Entity Framework Query combined with Stored Procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891647/server-side-execution-of-entity-framework-query-combined-with-stored-procedure)